# instanceof operator in java with interfaces

Tags: java, polymorphism, instanceof

Can anyone explain the following behavior in Java using instanceof operator .

```
Runnable r = new Thread();
```

eventhough the type of variable r is Runnable and the instanceof comparison is done on classes that do not reside in the same class hierarchy

```
System.out.println(r instanceof String); // This line does not compile 

System.out.println(r instanceof Vector); // This line compiles

System.out.println(r instanceof FileNotFoundException); // This line compiles
```

Answer (score 3):

`String` class is `final` -- that means it can't be subclassed. Moreover, it doesn't implement `Runnable`. All of this is known at compile time; hence, compilation error.

Comment: More to the point: `String` doesn't implement `Runnable`, and it can't have *subclasses* that do (because it's `final`).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes +1 this would be good to edit into the answer to make it more useful

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt: Yes. I was leaving it to Maurice. But the whole thing is a dupe anyway, so...

Answer (score 1):

An example:

```
static class First {

}

static final class Second {

}
```

And than :

```
    Runnable r = new Thread();

    System.out.println(r instanceof First);

    System.out.println(r instanceof Second);
```

The compiler sees that `Second` is `final`, thus it can not have any `sub-classes`, thus it can not implement `Runnable`.

Answer (score 0):

The `String` class is `final` and it doesn't implement the `Runnable` interface. Hence, `r instanceof String` can never return true (since there cannot be any sub-class of `String` that would implement `Runnable`), which is why the compiler doesn't allow it.

On the other hand, there may be sub-classes of the `Vector` class or the `FileNotFoundException` class that implement the `Runnable` interface, so `r instanceof Vector` and `r instanceof FileNotFoundException` may return true as far as the compiler can tell.

This is covered by [JLS 15.20.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2):

> If a cast (§15.16) of the RelationalExpression to the ReferenceType would be rejected as a compile-time error, then the instanceof relational expression likewise produces a compile-time error. **In such a situation, the result of the instanceof expression could never be true**.